# Matchstick dice game winning strategy

Tags: combinatorics, proof-writing, contest-math, problem-solving, game-theory

so I have been working on this problem for several days now. The fact that I can‘t find a solution is driving me crazy. I hope you guys can help me out. Here comes the problem:

> *Let there be 2022 nuts on the table. Two squirrels, Alice and Bob, take turns eating the nuts. To determine the number of nuts they eat
> on a given turn, they tip a regular dice over and eat the number that
> is on top. The last one unable to make a move loses the game. For
> which starting number a can Bob force a win?*

I thank anybody who leaves an answer.

Yours,
MathGuy :))))))

Comment: The rules are not clear.  When you say "tip a regular die over" the implication is that the next number must be one of the $4$ faces adjoining the current face.  Is that what you intended?  Or did you just mean "picks a number from $1$ to $6$"?

Comment: What do you know about modular arithmetic?

Comment: Regardless of what you intended the rules to be, the usual method for solving games like this is to start with smaller numbers.  Keep a list of winners and losers.  Generally speaking, a pattern emerges quickly and then it's usually not so hard to prove that it holds.

Comment: @lulu yes I mean that the next number must be on of the 4 adjoining faces. And yes, I tried it with smaller numbers but I am not able to generalise the result to 2022.

Comment: &Andrew Chin I know the basics. For example I know how to add subtract multiply numbers modulo some number.

Comment: So I just edited out a spelling mistake I found right now whilst looking over the text again. So don‘t be surprised.

Comment: So, suppose the starting face is $1$.  What are the first few winning numbers for $B$?

Comment: There will  have to be a recursion at some point.  Note that the winners and losers switch sides after each roll so the recursion shouldn't be all that terrible.

Comment: As another comment:  note that you haven't been clear as to how the endgame works.   If the die shows $i$ (after tipping) but there are fewer than $i$ nuts remaining, is that a loss or does the player just eat whatever is left and then claim victory?  These games always come down to details.

Comment: @lulu yes, it is considered a loss when the die shows a number higher than the number of nuts available. And as to your other questions, aschepler gave a very nice answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can describe the current game state as $(n,d)$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}$ (including zero) is the number of nuts remaining and $d \in \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ is the number on the top face of the die, together with the next player to move. Since the rules are symmetric for Alice and Bob, it will be enough to determine whether each $(n,d)$ is a winning or losing state for the current player, assuming ideal play.

The valid moves are from state $(n,a)$ to state $(n-b,b)$ where $a \neq b$ and $a+b \neq 7$. Note the moves from state $(n,a)$ and $(n,7-a)$ are the same, so those two states are always both winning or both losing. So the discussion below will usually just describe the states $(n,1), (n,2), (n,3)$, since the states $(n,6), (n,5), (n,4)$ respectively act the same. (There are still up to six different possible moves from each state, since they will result in different $n$ values. Just the states before and after moves are combined this way.)

As a base case, $(n,a)$ is a losing state if $n$ is smaller than the minimum possible next die face $b$, meaning there is no valid next move. $(0,a)$ (no nuts left) is always a losing state. If $a=1$ or $a=6$ then $b \geq 2$, so $(1,1)$ is a losing state.

Otherwise, a state is a winning state if ANY next move transitions to a losing state. A state is a losing state if EVERY next move transitions to a winning state.

Now let's look at the set of winning and losing $(n,d)$ for each $n$ value until a pattern is suggested.

$(0,d)$ loses.

$(1,1)$ loses. $(1,2)$ and $(1,3)$ win by stepping to $(0,1)$.

$(2,1)$ and $(2,3)$ win by stepping to $(0,2)$. $(2,2)$ wins by stepping to $(1,1)$.

$(3,1)$ and $(3,2)$ win by stepping to $(0,3)$. $(3,3)$ loses since $(2,1)$ and $(1,2)$ win.

$(4,1)$ and $(4,2)$ win by stepping to $(0,4)$. $(4,3)$ loses since  $(3,1)$ and $(2,2)$ win.

$(5,1)$ and $(5,3)$ win by stepping to $(0,5)$. $(5,2)$ loses since $(4,1), (2,3), (1,4)$ all win.

$(6,d)$ can always win by stepping to losing state $(0,6)$ or $(3,3)$. At least one of those must be possible.

$(7,d)$ can always win by stepping to losing state $(1,6)$ or $(3,4)$ or $(4,3)$ or $(5,2)$.

$(8,1)$ and $(8,2)$ win by stepping to $(4,4)$. $(8,3)$ loses since $(2,6), (3,5), (6,2), (7,1)$ all win.

$(9,d)$ loses for any $d$ since $(3,6), (4,5), (5,4), (6,3), (7,2), (8,1)$ all win.

$(10,d)$ can always win by stepping to $(5,5)$ or $(9,1)$.

$(11,d)$ can always win by stepping to $(8,3)$ or $(9,2)$.

$(12,1)$ and $(12,2)$ win by stepping to $(8,4)$ or $(9,3)$. $(12,3)$ loses since $(6,6), (7,5), (10,2), (11,1)$ all win.

$(13,1)$ and $(13,2)$ win by stepping to $(9,4)$. $(13,3)$ loses since $(7,6), (8,5), (11,2), (12,1)$ all win.

$(14,1)$ and $(14,3)$ win by stepping to $(9,5)$. $(14,2)$ loses since $(8,6), (10,4), (11,3), (13,1)$ all win.

$(15,d)$ can always win by stepping to $(9,6)$ or $(12,3)$.

$(16,d)$ can always win by stepping to $(12,4)$ or $(13,3)$ or $(14,2)$.

$(17,1)$ and $(17,2)$ win by stepping to $(13,4)$. $(17,3)$ loses since $(11,6), (12,5), (15,2), (16,1)$ all win.

$(18,d)$ loses for any $d$ since $(12,6), (13,5), (14,4), (15,3), (16,2), (17,1)$ all win.

Looks like the sets of winning $d$ repeat as $n$ increases, with period $9$, starting from $n=3$. Since the future sets of winning $d$ depend only on the previous $6$ sets of winning $d$, the pattern must continue. To be more careful, we could prove by induction that for $n \geq 3$, $(n,d)$ is a losing state if and only if $n \equiv 0 \pmod 9$ or ($n \in \{3,4,8\} \pmod 9$ and $d \in \{3,4\}$) or ($n \equiv 5 \pmod 9$ and $d \in \{2,5\}$).

For the question posed, the initial state before Alice's first move is $(2022, a)$. $2022 \equiv 6 \pmod 9$, so this is a winning state no matter what $a$ is. Alice can always turn the die either to $3$, leaving losing state $(2019,3)$, or to $6$, leaving losing state $(2016,6)$. Unless I've made a mistake or misunderstood the question, Alice can force a win no matter what the value $a$ is, and Bob never can.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. Really helped a lot.